# Only working default controller index. other functions not working or my routes wrong?

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

*****I cannot find my bug or server problems?

```
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(false);

$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->get('/lyuk', 'Home::lyuk');
```

And.htaccess file

Options All -Indexes

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
    ServerSignature Off
```

Comment: $routes->get('/', 'Home::index');   
$routes->get('/lyuk', 'Home::lyuk'); - this not working 
in debug monitor showing this. But i can't access to  Home::lyuk .   thi ihave lyuk.php in views.  
DEFINED ROUTES
Method Route Handler
GET / \App\Controllers\Home::index
GET lyuk \App\Controllers\Home::lyuk

Comment: this in app.php /n
`code` public $uriProtocol = 'REQUEST_URI'; `code`

Comment: No input file specified..
/lyuk.
if i use /index.php/lyuk    .this working fine

Comment: Did you try appending index.php to the path? Before you route while hitting the API?

Comment: Yes i using now url with index.php/  . Very hard to change this. in Codeigniter 3 all worked fine . only in Ci4 created problem with this

Comment: It's a problem of htaccess file in public folder. I will share mine later and see if works for you.

Comment: I had changed one line in htaccess file : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] . This worked for me.

Comment: i copied .hta and index.php to root folder. and deleted public folder. and i have RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]   . This still working but only with index.php in url.